# How to pass Int Array from Razor to Controller in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to to pass an array of `int` from `Razor` view to controller

I tried this it gave me one line "1","2" not two items

```
    public List<int> SelectedIDs { get; set; }

     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SelectedIDs, new { id = "hid" })

     $('#document').submit(function () {

        $("#hid").val($('#dropdownOne').val());

      });
```

Comment: Can you share controller code?

Answer (score 1):

`HiddenFor` doesn't work with arrays and lists. You should create list of `hidden` `input`s:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Model.SelectedIDs.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SelectedIDs)
}
```

Note that i use `for` loop instead of `foreach` becouse foreach will break binding.

And then if you wrap your hidden filds with a `form` tag it will bind automatically to your model in controller on `form` **POST**.

Comment: Thank you teo van kot for your help. but how i will assign value from dropdownlist to hide field like this  $("#hid").val($('#dropdownOne').val());